# ElasticSearch Query/Result Optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

having an elastic search query, need to find its optimization because it takes more CPU time and memory, my first thought is to some changes required in parent/child relationship, How can I optimize this elasticsearch query or change the mapping to get the same result.

```
GET trending/_search

{
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "size":-1,
   "sort":[
      {
         "id":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "type":"post"
               }
            },
            {
               "terms":{
                  "post_type_id":[
                     1,
                     2,
                     5,
                     7
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "has_parent":{
                  "parent_type":"user",
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "should":[
                           {
                              "bool":{
                                 "must":{
                                    "has_child":{
                                       "type":"followers",
                                       "query":{
                                          "bool":{
                                             "must":[
                                                {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "status":"A"
                                                   }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "user_id":87
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "bool":{
                                 "must":[
                                    {
                                       "terms":{
                                          "id":[
                                             5,
                                             14,
                                             19,
                                             30,
                                             31,
                                             60,
                                             64,
                                             72,
                                             74,
                                             75,
                                             77,
                                             80,
                                             81,
                                             85,
                                             92,
                                             101,
                                             112,
                                             138,
                                             139,
                                             189,
                                             196,
                                             201,
                                             205,
                                             210,
                                             211,
                                             224,
                                             238,
                                             239,
                                             274,
                                             275,
                                             283,
                                             336,
                                             421,
                                             434,
                                             585,
                                             633,
                                             649,
                                             687,
                                             788,
                                             836,
                                             1442,
                                             1479,
                                             1607,
                                             1699,
                                             1775,
                                             1779,
                                             1784,
                                             1823,
                                             1863,
                                             1868,
                                             1899,
                                             2131,
                                             2170,
                                             2329,
                                             2376,
                                             2389,
                                             2401,
                                             2405,
                                             2508,
                                             2568,
                                             2802,
                                             2892,
                                             3074,
                                             3082,
                                             3196,
                                             3312,
                                             3315,
                                             3326,
                                             3391,
                                             3520,
                                             3765,
                                             3853,
                                             3983,
                                             4037,
                                             4436,
                                             4533,
                                             4936,
                                             5018,
                                             5116,
                                             5131,
                                             5353,
                                             5653,
                                             5673,
                                             5674,
                                             5699,
                                             5713,
                                             5789,
                                             5837,
                                             5889,
                                             6391,
                                             6586,
                                             6641,
                                             6819,
                                             6872,
                                             6942,
                                             7302,
                                             7427,
                                             7765,
                                             7828,
                                             8204,
                                             8205,
                                             8402,
                                             8608,
                                             8625,
                                             8655,
                                             8695,
                                             9026,
                                             9116,
                                             9365,
                                             9430,
                                             9600,
                                             14080,
                                             14594,
                                             16543,
                                             17115,
                                             17118,
                                             17825,
                                             17914,
                                             18323,
                                             18368,
                                             18371,
                                             18636,
                                             19071,
                                             19415,
                                             19418,
                                             19632,
                                             19712,
                                             19727,
                                             19978,
                                             20000,
                                             20433,
                                             21132,
                                             23015,
                                             24514,
                                             25266,
                                             25601,
                                             27300,
                                             28493,
                                             28658,
                                             29433,
                                             29441,
                                             29460,
                                             29604,
                                             30104,
                                             30176,
                                             30525,
                                             30965,
                                             31072,
                                             31130,
                                             31497,
                                             31915,
                                             32004,
                                             32184,
                                             32294,
                                             32337,
                                             34053,
                                             36019,
                                             36246,
                                             36986
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "has_child":{
                  "type":"post_box",
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "must":[
                           {
                              "terms":{
                                 "status":[
                                    "A",
                                    "F"
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "created_at":{
                     "lte":"2022-06-28T05:18:17Z"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

and here is the result of the query,

````
    {
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "London Restaurants",
          "searchable_title" : "London Restaurants",
          "user_id" : 3,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-17T08:48:05Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-3",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "name" : "Exploring England",
          "searchable_title" : "Exploring England",
          "user_id" : 3,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-17T08:53:18Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-3",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 5,
          "name" : """Friends""",
          "searchable_title" : """Friends""",
          "user_id" : 5,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-10-02T04:56:57Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-5",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-10",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 10,
          "name" : "water",
          "searchable_title" : "water",
          "user_id" : 7,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-20T06:11:21Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-7",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-11",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 11,
          "name" : "leggings ",
          "searchable_title" : "leggings ",
          "user_id" : 7,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-20T06:12:55Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-7",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-14",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 14,
          "name" : "new tech",
          "searchable_title" : "new tech",
          "user_id" : 8,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-23T04:04:05Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-8",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-16",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 16,
          "name" : "Adventure",
          "searchable_title" : "Adventure",
          "user_id" : 16,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-26T11:18:56Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-16",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-17",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 17,
          "name" : "nights out",
          "searchable_title" : "nights out",
          "user_id" : 8,
          "status" : "A",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-27T05:03:22Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-8",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-18",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 18,
          "name" : "boxxx",
          "searchable_title" : "boxxx",
          "user_id" : 18,
          "status" : "F",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-27T05:03:35Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-18",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "trending",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bx-19",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "3",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 19,
          "name" : "animals ",
          "searchable_title" : "animals ",
          "user_id" : 18,
          "status" : "F",
          "created_at" : "2017-01-27T05:07:27Z",
          "type" : {
            "parent" : "u-18",
            "name" : "box"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}```
   
And here is the mappings of the index,
````

```
      {
  "trending" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "box_id" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "categories" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "category_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "chat_channel" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "delete_one" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "delete_two" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "device_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "dob" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "email" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "friend_box" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "friend_posts" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "full_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
            },
            "edgengram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer" : "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
            },
            "fv_search" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "fv_search_analyzer"
            },
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "search_edgenGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_edgenGram_analyzer"
            },
            "search_nGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_nGram_analyzer"
            },
            "special_character" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "alphanumeric_string_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "term_vector" : "yes",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard",
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "gender" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "is_live" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "is_verified" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "item_type_number" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "message_content" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "message_object" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "message_privacy" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
            },
            "edgengram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer" : "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
            },
            "fv_search" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "fv_search_analyzer"
            },
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "search_edgenGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_edgenGram_analyzer"
            },
            "search_nGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_nGram_analyzer"
            },
            "special_character" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "alphanumeric_string_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "term_vector" : "yes",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard",
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "object_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "phone" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          },
          "term_vector" : "yes"
        },
        "phone_post_fix" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "picture" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "post_id" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "post_media" : {
          "properties" : {
            "bg_color" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "file" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "file_type_number" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "medium_file_height" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "medium_file_width" : {
              "type" : "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "post_type_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "private_box" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "private_posts" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "public_box" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "public_posts" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "searchable_title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
            },
            "edgengram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer" : "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
            },
            "fv_search" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "fv_search_analyzer"
            },
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "search_edgenGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_edgenGram_analyzer"
            },
            "search_nGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_nGram_analyzer"
            },
            "special_character" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "alphanumeric_string_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "term_vector" : "yes",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard",
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "source_key" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "status" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "type" : {
          "type" : "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals" : true,
          "relations" : {
            "post" : [
              "discover_views",
              "post_box"
            ],
            "box" : "box_post",
            "user" : [
              "followers",
              "post",
              "blocked",
              "followings",
              "messages",
              "box",
              "block"
            ]
          }
        },
        "uid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "user_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "username" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
            },
            "edgengram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer" : "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
            },
            "fv_search" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "fv_search_analyzer"
            },
            "raw" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "search_edgenGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_edgenGram_analyzer"
            },
            "search_nGram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "search_nGram_analyzer"
            },
            "special_character" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "alphanumeric_string_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "term_vector" : "yes",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard",
          "fielddata" : true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the somewhat optimized query , I totally remove the has_parent and has child join at above the query to get the friends, getting it from the db and providing the ids in simple terms query,

```
          GET trending/_search
{"size": 40, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "post"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "post_type_id": [
              1,
              2,
              5,
              7
            ]
          }
        },
      {                                       "terms":{
                                          "user_id":[
                                             5,
                                             14,
                                             19,
                                             30,
                                             31,
                                             60,
                                             64,
                                             72,
                                             74,
                                             75,
                                             77,
                                             80,
                                             81,
                                             85,
                                             92,
                                             101,
                                             112,
                                             138,
                                             139,
                                             189,
                                             196,
                                             201,
                                             205,
                                             210,
                                             211,
                                             224,
                                             238,
                                             239,
                                             274,
                                             275,
                                             283,
                                             336,
                                             421,
                                             434,
                                             585,
                                             633,
                                             649,
                                             687,
                                             788,
                                             836,
                                             1442,
                                             1479,
                                             1607,
                                             1699,
                                             1775,
                                             1779,
                                             1784,
                                             1823,
                                             1863,
                                             1868,
                                             1899,
                                             2131,
                                             2170,
                                             2329,
                                             2376,
                                             2389,
                                             2401,
                                             2405,
                                             2508,
                                             2568,
                                             2802,
                                             2892,
                                             3074,
                                             3082,
                                             3196,
                                             3312,
                                             3315,
                                             3326,
                                             3391,
                                             3520,
                                             3765,
                                             3853,
                                             3983,
                                             4037,
                                             4436,
                                             4533,
                                             4936,
                                             5018,
                                             5116,
                                             5131,
                                             5353,
                                             5653,
                                             5673,
                                             5674,
                                             5699,
                                             5713,
                                             5789,
                                             5837,
                                             5889,
                                             6391,
                                             6586,
                                             6641,
                                             6819,
                                             6872,
                                             6942,
                                             7302,
                                             7427,
                                             7765,
                                             7828,
                                             8204,
                                             8205,
                                             8402,
                                             8608,
                                             8625,
                                             8655,
                                             8695,
                                             9026,
                                             9116,
                                             9365,
                                             9430,
                                             9600,
                                             14080,
                                             14594,
                                             16543,
                                             17115,
                                             17118,
                                             17825,
                                             17914,
                                             18323,
                                             18368,
                                             18371,
                                             18636,
                                             19071,
                                             19415,
                                             19418,
                                             19632,
                                             19712,
                                             19727,
                                             19978,
                                             20000,
                                             20433,
                                             21132,
                                             23015,
                                             24514,
                                             25266,
                                             25601,
                                             27300,
                                             28493,
                                             28658,
                                             29433,
                                             29441,
                                             29460,
                                             29604,
                                             30104,
                                             30176,
                                             30525,
                                             30965,
                                             31072,
                                             31130,
                                             31497,
                                             31915,
                                             32004,
                                             32184,
                                             32294,
                                             32337,
                                             34053,
                                             36019,
                                             36246,
                                             36986
                                          ]
                                       }
},
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "post_box",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "status": [
                        "A",
                        "F"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "lte": "2022-07-06T07:19:39Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: and for info devs also used the nested object while insert the data in this index, so index has both parent/child joins and also nested objects .

Answer (score 0):

Denormalize the data. Add keys to the parents and children identifying the connecting record. Put everything into one index. Your search will become way faster and won't use so much CPU.

Stop using parent child mappings completely.Its a waste of time and memory.

HTH.

Comment: yeah but all the parent child documents are in the sama index, I need to optimize the quqery , and the way I am going this is, in my answer , if you can comment on this by comparing the query in question and in my answer , I am providing the friends id from db any way so why to use the has_parent and has_child query above totally can remove this, 
also I am working on to denormalize the postboxes cause getting only status from this relation ,